# codemirror Hints are behind the editor ISSUE

Tags: css, codemirror, codemirror-modes, ui-codemirror

I am getting issue with Codemirror editor when I am pressing ctrl-space then codemirror are active and display behind the editor that is why hints are not actually visible on editor.
Can someone help on this.